# Textfields inside table cells losing textproperty in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I inserted textfields in table cells as shown below,

[image: table containing textfileds as rows]

and I gave textproperty to the fields qty,sqf,rate(see image). Each row is inserted by pressing 'ENTER' button from keyboard(am calling a function for inserting textfields to table cells). When I enter values in qty,sqf etc. am doing some calculations and result is shown in last column.
When I inserted first row, .textproperty is working correctly and am getting calculated value in last column. Same thing is working for other rows too...

But my problem is that,

after inserting row2, textproperty of row1 is not working. Similary textproperty of row1 and row2 is not working when inserted row3.Means textproprty is working only for last inserted row (not working for already inserted row). Why is this so? and how can I correct it??
I am calling textproperty function in initialize() function.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant parts of the code. It is very hard to understand what you actually do without it.

Comment: @Itai see the edited question